# Is there a way in Python to update multiple random values in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I am working on a schedule generator, and I need to randomly put two days off into it. I came up with a solution, however I noticed that randinit method can put two days off on one day, so this option doesn't work for me.

```
import random

schedule = {1: "9:00 - 17:00", 2: "9:00 - 17:00", 3: "16:00 - 00:00", 4: "16:00 - 00:00", 5: "16:00 - 00:00", 6: "16:00 - 00:00", 7: "16:00 - 00:00"}
days_off = {random.randint(1, 7): "X", random.randint(1, 7): "X"}

schedule.update(days_off)
```

So I am thinking that there should be an easier way to make it work without hardcoding, but I cannot really find it.

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), which allows you to randomly select multiple *different* values from a given population:

```py
for d in random.sample(range(1, 7+1), k=2):
    schedule[d] = "X"
```

Comment: `random.choices` works with replacement, this could yield the same number twice.

Comment: @JanJaapMeijerink whoops my bad, always confuse the two. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
for day_off in np.random.choice(np.arange(7), size=2, replace=False):
    shedule[day_off + 1] = "X"
```